# Using auto layout and creating dynamic interface (realigning automatically when field hidden)

Tags: ios, xcode5, constraints, uistoryboard

Using Xcode5 and auto layout. Consider following scenario:

[image]

I have an outlet for "Dispatch" UITextField

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dispatchTextField;
```

If user clicks "Camera" button I want to hide dispatchTextField and move "Subject" and "Body"(below) up.

This is not a real scenario but I'm facing tasks where I will be using this kind of technique. I've seen code samples where container size can be modified and so on. In XAML - there is "StackPanel", in Android there is similar controls where I can just hide this TextField and views below automatically spring up.

So, what is the *proper* way to do this in XCode5 with auto-layout?

I tried (with no luck)

```
self.recipientTextField.hidden = YES;
```

I also tried

```
[self.recipientTextField setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a height constraint to the text field. After making sure there are no conflicting vertical constraints, add a reference to this constraint in your view controller.

Add an action to the Camera button and connect it to the view controller. Whenever the button is tapped, you would set the `constant` property of the height constraint to zero.

Make sure that other views are setup to have constant vertical spacing with the text field you wish to shrink.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Do you have suggestion on how to avoid doing 2 constraint outlets? For this particular example, there is constraint for vertical spacing between field I'm hiding and Camera button. So, I would have to set this one to 0 as well, otherwise I will get double-spacing between Camera and Subject fields

Comment: @katit That's the thing with Auto Layout. Ease of use comes at the cost of brevity. You'd have to update both constraints.